# Compactification of a topological semigroup with right-identity structure

Tags: topological-groups, semigroups, alexandroff-compactification

I'm looking for a hint on this question:

Let $T$ be as a semigroup with right-identity structure i.e. $rs=r$ for all $r, s\in T$. Also, we consider $T$ as a  topological semigroup  that is a locally compact, noncompact Hausdorff
space. Define $X=T\cup \{\infty \}$ to be the one-point compactification of $T$.

Also, assume that $U$ be an open set of $\infty$. Is there a compact set $K$ in $T$ such that $(U-\{\infty\})\subseteq K$?

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the role of $e$? Is $U$ an open set of $X$?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin, $e\in T$ is means that $T$ is  monoid. Yes $U$ is an open set of $X$.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify. Moreover, if $e$ is the identity, $es = s$ for all $s$, contrary to your assumption.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin, Thanks. in my question, I assume that $T$ is a topological semigroup and I edited it.